# problems with ros installation on pandaboard with armhf

Tags: rosdep, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, pandaboard, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am trying to install ros on a Pandaboard Rev A4 based on the armhf architecture on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Since no binary Packages are available for armhf, I have to built ros from source according to

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

which turns out not to be easy. However, I have been able to get the ros core libraries running. Yet, the higher level libraries are causing problems. I follow the instructions up to step 1.3 where rosdep keeps crashing after executing "rosdep install -ay"

I know that the problem is that some dependencies are not available for armhf. I tried to install some of them from source, for example yaml-cpp according to this post:

http://answers.ros.org/question/36319/how-to-install-yaml-cpp026-dev-how-to-install-from-source-correctly/

or swig-wx according to the instructions at

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

but they are NOT detected by ros then. yaml-cpp is only one of the missing dependencies:

```
bruewer@panda-desktop:~/ros/simulator_gazebo$ rosdep check -a
System dependencies have not been satisified:
apt libtbb-dev
apt nvidia-cg-toolkit
apt ros-fuerte-ros
apt yaml-cpp
apt ros-fuerte-opencv2
apt ros-fuerte-swig-wx
```

Installing nvidia-cg-toolkit doesnt even make sense for my PandaBoard, as there is no nvidia GPU available. But that library may be a special case and I read (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5490) that the ros guys are currently working on this. How to I install the missing libs and integrate them with ros? I have been trying to figure this out for days and do not get any further. Any help is appreciated!

Cheers,
Bryan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44208/problems-with-ros-installation-on-pandaboard-with-armhf/) by [brhempen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3117/brhempen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-10-02**:
Are you trying to install desktop-full onto a Pandaboard? Can you try installing a simpler ROS variant, such as robot or mobile? See http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0113.html#robot-variant for a list of variants.

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-10-02**:
I installed ROS on a Pandaboard but without 3D rendering. By the way, I don't think that gazebo or something else will run on the ARM board.

Is it essential to your project that you visualize everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is also an installation tutorial for ROS Groovy on Raspbian Pi:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source

Based on this I created a tutorial for ROS Groovy running under Ubuntu 12.04 on a PandaBoard:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source

It's recommended to use the robot installation.

Hope this will help somebody.

---

Originally posted by [zumili](https://answers.ros.org/users/3935/zumili/) with karma: 141 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2013-01-29**:
is the openni_launch package working? this was the hardest part and the reason why I gave up and ended up with ROS electric + ubuntu 11.10

**Comment by [zumili](https://answers.ros.org/users/3935/zumili/) on 2013-01-29**:
We didnt tested it, because we only have the robot version of groovy running on the Panda. There are a lot of errors trying to install a Desktop version of groovy on a Panda at the moment, but have a look at the Raspbian tutorial (Desktop) for groovy. With luck you get all deps for openni.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that the nvidia toolkit has successfully been removed from the dependency tree in Groovy.  [package.xml](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/groovy-devel/package.xml)

There's also a group working on [Groovy on Raspberry Pi installation instructions](http://ros.org/wiki/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1